# what is meant by -u option in git

Tags: git

i have started with git.

I want to know what the option `-u` does.

So what is the difference between :

1. `git add`   vs  `git add -u`
2. `git push` vs `git push -u`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Add, `-u` will make it only add updated files - eg. ones that you have already tracked/committed previously.

[Manual entry for Add](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html)

For Push, `-u` will make it track the remote branch, so when you do `git status` it will let you know how many commits ahead/behind the remote branch you are at.

[Manual entry for Push](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reading the help?

```
git help add
git help push
```

to access it.

As for the specifics:

`git add -u` does the same as `git add .` except that it doesn't add untracked files, which the latter does.

`git push -u` sets the local branch as tracking the remote branch. Generally you only use it when you first push a new branch, and git will even tell you to use it then if you just type `git push` by mistake (it uses the long name `--set-upstream`).